# ArrayList returns same value while looping

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an arraylist object of Drugs. I have 5 objects in the `drugsList`.

So `drugsList.size()` returns 5. 5 drugs are in `drugsList` with `drugName`, `description` and `category`.

I want to return 5 times a `DrugsFragment` with with `name`, `description` and `category`. What happens now is that it creates the fragment 5 times but it each fragment has the same `name`, `description` and `category` value. I am 100% sure that the lists contains 5 drugs with 5 different `names/category/description`.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    DrugsFragment df = null;
    for(int i= 0; i < drugsList.size() ; i++) {
        drugName = drugsList.get(i).getName();
        description = drugsList.get(i).getDescription();
        category = drugsList.get(i).getCategory();

         df = DrugsFragment.newInstance(drugName, description,category);
    }

    return df;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here when returning the `newInstance`?

Comment: Return a `List<DrugFragment>` rather than a single `DrugFragment`.

Comment: That is not an option in the way my project has been set up now. And i would like to understand what is going wrong instead of just trying something.

Comment: You are creating 5 Fragments and only using the last one every time, regardless of the position passed in.  I'm a bit unsure why you have a loop at all.

Comment: It's happening because you are overriding what's in `df` each time so it's returning the last one.

Comment: Well, you have to understand that you're declaring a single `DrugFragment` and re initializing it on every iteration of the `for` loop. No matter what you currently do in the `for` loop, you only have a single `DrugsFragment`. If you want/need to have several fragments, return a `List`. If you can't for whatever you say, then store a list with proper data inside the `DrugFragment` or another class and pass this list to your single `DrugFragment`. If that's not an option either, then maybe your design is broken.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation luiggi now i understand it, won't make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everytime you call that function, you loop through the list and create a new instance of `Fragment`, then you return the last `Fragment` you created from the function as the result.

Instead, you just need to get the item off the `drugsList` at the position you want.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {         
    String drugName = drugsList.get(position).getName();
    String description = drugsList.get(position).getDescription();
    String category = drugsList.get(position).getCategory();

    return DrugsFragment.newInstance(drugName, description,category);
}
```

To get 5 you'd do something like this:

```
for(int i= 0; i < drugsList.size() ; i++) {
    var Fragment = getItem(i);
}
```

You'd need to give `getItem()` a way to access this list, perhaps the above loop might be in another class method.

Comment: Ok that is a clear answer thanks for that. I try to loop because i want it to loop through the array take, the 5 values and assign them each time to a fragment. I totally understand your logic but i don't know how to set that up. Can maybe show some prepcode how to do that?

Comment: This was the easiest way to achieve it. Thank's for you help and explanation Robert.